# GraphQL Datatable, how to access the field of a field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have a query in GraphQL as follows:

```
person {
id
title {
name
}
}
```

I am having an issue to pass to the datatable component the name of the title as a reference.

I define the columns as follows, but as it is expected the title name doesn't display. Any idea on how to reference the title name?

```
 const columns = [
    {
      name: "id",
      label: "ID",
    },
    {
      name: "title.name",
      label: "Title Name",
    }
]
```

Comment: custom `selector` or `cell` ?

Comment: @xadm how would you do it?

Comment: it's not about me ... what did you do with these hints?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, one has to do as follows:

```
  {
      name: "title",
      label: "Title",
      options: { 
        customBodyRender: (dataIndex, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return dataIndex.title;
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: you should mention it's not about react-data-table-component